# Reading the contents of directories in Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to accomplish two things with a Perl script. I have a file, which in the first subdirectory has different user directories, and in each of these user directories contains some folders that have text files in them. I am trying to write a Perl script that

1. Lists the directories for each user
2. Gets the total number of `.txt` files

For the second objective I have this code

```
my @emails = glob "$dir/*.txt";
for (0..$#emails){
    $emails[$_] =~ s/\.txt$//;
}
$emails=@emails;
```

but `$emails` is returning 0. Any insight?

Comment: That means `@emails` is empty. That means `glob` returned an empty list. That means your glob pattern isn't what you think it is, or it doesn't mean what you think it means. What's the output of `{ use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print(Dumper($dir)); }`

Comment: $VAR1 = "Emails"; This is the name of the directory I'm looking for. The issue is that what I'm trying to get to is in one or two directories below, spread across a few different users.

Comment: What's the current work directory (`use Cwd; print cwd, "\n";`), and is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes, I just am having issues reaching the subdirectories,(and retrieving the number of .txt files in these), not the directory I'm calling the script from.

Comment: My question wasn't a yes/no question. And if you want me to see your replies, be sure to use `@ikegami` in them!

Comment: What's the path returned by `cwd`, and what's the full path to one of the files? Also, do you use `glob` anywhere else?

Comment: "is it what you expect it to be?" "My question wasn't a yes/no question." The full path is something like Emails/user/user_specific/email.txt or /Emails/user/user_specific/user_specificagain/email.txt I simply would like to know how to return the glob of all sub directories @ikegami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, using glob is not very good idea when it comes to processing files in directories and possible subdirectories.
Much better way is to use File::Find module, like this:

```
use File::Find;

my @emails;

File::Find::find(
    {
        # this will be called for each file under $dir:
        wanted => sub {
            my $file = $File::Find::name;
            return unless -f $file and $file =~ /\.txt$/;
            # this file looks like email, remember it:
            push @emails, $file;
        }
    },
    $dir
);

print "Found " . scalar @emails . " .txt files (emails) in '$dir'\n";
```

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the answer I was looking for.